# Adding Pagination causes 500 Server Error

Tags: error, pagination, ee5

I am running EE 5.3.2.

Using the following code I am have issues with page loads that end in 500 Server Error

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" category="184" limit="21" paginate="bottom" }       
    <div class="col-lg-4 position-relative">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="{entry_thumbnail}" alt="{title}" />
        <h2 class="text-center double-row">{title}</h2>
        <p class="summary-block">{brief_summary}</p>
        
        <div class="text-center center-bottom">
            <a class="btn read" href="/new/blog/{url_title}" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    
    {paginate}
    <div class="col-12">
        <p class="text-right">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    </div>
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I remove the pagination code everything works fine. Any clues what may be causing this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Pagination in EE works by adding a segment to the end of your URI - so my guess is that you have an issue with routing.

Try loading your template with the pagination block removed (i.e. so you get the page) and then add `/P5`to the end of your URI and see what you get.  If you get the 500 error, then that would confirm the issue.

What you do next depends a bit on whether the site as a whole is working - if you can navigate between pages OK then it would suggest the issue is pagination itself, if you cannot navigate easily within the site, either the EE config or the .htaccess file might be the issue.

Just to eliminate such from your consideration, also have a look at whether there is any routing over-rides in use (e.g. from the EE [Template Routes](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/template-manager.html#template-routes) area, or an add-on such as [Detour Pro](https://eeharbor.com/detour-pro/documentation/usage)); if you have such check to make sure that the routes being changed include consideration of the EE pagination slugs.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have circled back to this issue and add /P5 to the URI. The page loads fine. In general the site works fine - has worked fine for more than three years. I don't use Temple Routes for Detour Pro. Is it possible the 301 for https: could be a problem with the pagination?